# Views profile2 views

Tags: views, users

I hope it's okay to ask a why question here. I've got a profile named Expert Information and a Skills field in that profile. I've got 9 users with the Expert role. Now my problem is: When I make a user type of view and make a relationship to profile, I get all 9 users but nothing shows under Skills; however when I make a profile type of view and make a relationship to user, I get results under Skills but this time I get 4 users. Why is that happening and what is the correct way to fulfill both?

Thanks,

K.

Comment: Is the skills field empty for any of the users? Reason I am asking is that AFAIK the profile 2 entity is only created when you actually add content to it. It is created on demand in a lazy load manner.

Comment: No, most of them have the skills field filled.

Comment: You are right, there is an issue. If you filter your view by profile type 'main profile', then it shows the 'expert' profile as well. In the database 'profile' table has 'type' set to main, when it must be expert. And 'profile_type' table is correct, however the sql query never joins on that table. It just filters on the join between users table and profile table on the profile.type, which as I mentioned is set to 'main' instead of 'expert. Please file a bug report about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my bad, the person who originally made the view did not make the relationship properly. But the weird thing is, it worked properly on a Drupal 7.30 installation and broke on 7.34.